new Image() w/ srcset: Do Browsers respect responsive images?
I am seeking information regarding the handling of srcset by various browsers when implemented through JavaScript, specifically using new Image().srcset. My primary interest lies in understanding whether browsers effectively download only the necessary image files based on the specified criteria.
Here is a code example for reference:
let img = new Image();
img.srcset = "https://images.placeholders.dev/?width=320&height=200&text=320w 320w, " +
             "https://images.placeholders.dev/?width=480&height=300&text=480w 480w, " +
             "https://images.placeholders.dev/?width=800&height=500&text=800w 800w";
img.sizes = "(max-width: 320px) 280px, (max-width: 480px) 440px, 800px";
img.src = "https://images.placeholders.dev/?width=1500&height=1500&text=1500w"; // Fallback source

Context: My objective is to preload images without attaching them to the current DOM, while ensuring that srcset functionality and responsive loading based on viewport size are appropriately respected.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or resources regarding browser support and behavior in this context.
Update
Test Procedure
I tested my browsers using this procedure:

Executed the above code in a new tab
Ensure cache is disabled in network tab
Set the device width via the dev tools to 300px
Checked the network tab which image was requested

Results
Chrome 120

❌ requests the 480px version, but not the 320px version
✅ requests the 800px version, if w>800px

Firefox 130

❌ requests the 800px version, but not the 320px version
seems to always request the 800px version

Fill-in
Please add your own results for a better overview.

Be aware that it might request an higher resolution image if you have an increased device pixel ratio or a lower resolution if you have prefers-reduced-data enabled

And when setting img.loading = 'lazy' loading will be disabled until the image is (almost) on screen.
